# Carga lenta de registros C#

Tags: c#, linq, wpf

Escribo esta entrada para preguntar sobre una posible **solución/ explicación** a uno de mis problemas que tengo con un proyecto. El proyecto es un proyecto de **C# WPF** en el que tengo varios menús y en uno de ellos (Articulos) tenemos una llamada algo pesada:

```
public ArticuloDTO ObtenerArticuloConId(int ArticuloID, bool CargarTodo = true)
    {
        try
        {
            ARTICULOS ArtBBDD;
            if (CargarTodo)
            {

                ArtBBDD = Context.ARTICULOS
                .Include(x => x.PROVEEDORES)
                .Include(x => x.MENSAJESART)
                .Include(x => x.CONJUNTOSARTICULOS1.Select(k => k.ARTICULOS))
                .Include(x => x.CONJUNTOSARTICULOS)
                .Include(x => x.IVA)
                .Include(x => x.IVA1)
                .Include(x => x.CODIGOSBARRAS)
                .Include(x => x.DESCUENTOSCLIE.Select(k => k.CLIENTES))
                .Include(x => x.DESCUENTOSPROV.Select(k => k.PROVEEDORES))
                .Include(x => x.MARGENES)
                .Include(x => x.PROVEEDORESART.Select(k => k.PROVEEDORES))
                .Include(x => x.ALMACENESART.Select(k => k.ALMACENES))
                .Include(x => x.COMISIONES)
                .Include(x => x.TASASRECICLAJE.Select(k => k.TASAS))
                .FirstOrDefault(Art => Art.ID == ArticuloID && Art.FBOR == null);

            }
            else
            {
                ArtBBDD = Context.ARTICULOS.FirstOrDefault(Art => Art.ID == ArticuloID && Art.FBOR == null);
            }
            ArticuloDTO dto = new ArticuloDTO();

            dto.Cargando = true;
            ArtBBDD.ReemplazarDatosDTO(ref dto);
            dto.Cargando = false;

            return dto;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

El problema reside en que cuando el usuario entra por **primera vez** a dicho menú, la primera carga de un articulo en concreto, que es este método, tarda alrededor de **10-15 segundos**; mientras que tras hacer una primera llamada, **las siguientes** no llegan a tardar ni **2-3 segundos**.

Actualmente y de manera "fea" y no "ortodoxa" he hecho que al cargar la aplicación se llama a dicho método con el primer registro que hubiese en la BBDD. Sé que el problema reside en la cantidad de relaciones y relaciones de éstas; pero... Alguien puede explicarme por qué a partir de la primera carga no tarda tanto como en la primera llamada?

Un saludo

Comment: Con el else esta la segunda Carga?, en este caso podrias usar AsParallel() para que la carga de trabajo se realize con todos los procesadores y la busqueda sea mas rapida. Tambien, te hace falta traer todo o podrias optimizar tu consulta?

Comment: Gracias por la contestación @RamiroBarone pero las llamadas que se hacen después de la primer carga entran siempre por el if, el else es en contadas ocasiones.
Por desgracia si que necesito los datos con los que están las relaciones, ya que estoy en la pantalla de dicho objeto (Articulos)

Comment: Primero, si realmente necesitas tantas relaciones... es que habría que revisar el diseño de la base de datos. Por otra parte, este método debería ser `async` para no bloquear el *thread* y éste mismo pueda ir haciendo trabajos de renderización (por ejemplo). Por último, el hecho de que la primera carga sea lenta y las otras rápidas es porque *EF* tiene un sistema de *caching* bastante potente precisamente para no tener que ir siempre a la base de datos si es que nada cambió, sólo accede a su *virtual context* en memoria, el cual es mucho más performante.

Comment: @Joselz94 la conexino a la base la estas haciendo con EF?

Comment: Sí @RamiroBarone La estoy haciendo con EF.
Voy a probar a hacerlo como pones en la respuesta porque creo que se solucionará. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Deberias realizar dos pasos para poder mejorar el rendimiento de tu llamada. Primero tu metodo deberia ser `async` o ejecutarlo en una `Task`, segundo tu consulta ejecutarla con `AsParallel()` para que divida el trabajo de la consulta en los procesadores que tenes disponible, la cantidad de procesadores la podes setear de forma manual o dejar que .Net lo decida.
Depende de en que linea agregas el `AsParallel()` es como vas a obtener el resultado en caso de tener mas de un registro.

1-la llamada a tu metodo podria ser asi:

```
var t = Task<ArticuloDTO>.Run(() => ObtenerArticuloConId(1, false));
t.Result; // -> aca tenes tu objeto para pasarlo a donde necesites.
```

2-Parallel

```
    public ArticuloDTO ObtenerArticuloConId(int ArticuloID, bool CargarTodo = true)
    {
        try
        {
            ARTICULOS ArtBBDD;
            if (CargarTodo)
            {

                ArtBBDD = Context.ARTICULOS.AsParallel()
                .Include(x => x.PROVEEDORES)
                .Include(x => x.MENSAJESART)
                .Include(x => x.CONJUNTOSARTICULOS1.Select(k => k.ARTICULOS))
                .Include(x => x.CONJUNTOSARTICULOS)
                .Include(x => x.IVA)
                .Include(x => x.IVA1)
                .Include(x => x.CODIGOSBARRAS)
                .Include(x => x.DESCUENTOSCLIE.Select(k => k.CLIENTES))
                .Include(x => x.DESCUENTOSPROV.Select(k => k.PROVEEDORES))
                .Include(x => x.MARGENES)
                .Include(x => x.PROVEEDORESART.Select(k => k.PROVEEDORES))
                .Include(x => x.ALMACENESART.Select(k => k.ALMACENES))
                .Include(x => x.COMISIONES)
                .Include(x => x.TASASRECICLAJE.Select(k => k.TASAS))
                .FirstOrDefault(Art => Art.ID == ArticuloID && Art.FBOR == null);

            }
            else
            {
                ArtBBDD = Context.ARTICULOS.FirstOrDefault(Art => Art.ID == ArticuloID && Art.FBOR == null);
            }
            ArticuloDTO dto = new ArticuloDTO();

            dto.Cargando = true;
            ArtBBDD.ReemplazarDatosDTO(ref dto);
            dto.Cargando = false;

            return dto;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone He probado tu respuesta y el código me decía que tenia que ser un Enumerable, hice los cambios necesario y aún así el código proporcionado no me servía puesto que seguía dando error. 

De todas formas, gracias por la ayuda y sigo investigando

Comment: Que error que da?

Comment: Okay! Solucionado Ramiro, he reducido al maximo las relaciones, puesto que parecia que no todas eras necesarias y ahora va como la seda.